# Forward optional arguments

Tags: macros

I have this body:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{image.png}
  \captionof{figure}{Image Caption}
\end{center}
```

But I'd like to simplify it to:

```
\mygraphics[scale=0.8]{image.png}{Image Caption}
```

with:

```
\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][???]{%
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[???]{#1}%
    \captionon{figure}{#2}%
  \end{center}%
}
```

Comment: Does this mean it's a simple matter of `\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][]{ ... \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\caption{figure}{#3}...}`?  Even if someone puts several options into it like `[xscale=\textwidth,yscale=\textheight]`?

Comment: `\newcommand{\mygraphics}[3][]{ ...}`. You have *three* arguments. The optional parameter is always the first.

Comment: Fro bottom up: replace `#2` with `#3`; `#1` with `#2`, `[???]` with `[#1]`; `[???]` with `[]`; `[2]` with `[3]`

Comment: I've just made those changes, but get an error.  Question updated.

Comment: As an aside, `\begin{center}\centering...` doesn't make much sense, `\begin{center}` should be enough.

Comment: Ok, yes that helps.  Thanks!  I needed to delete `*.{aux,toc,lof}` and rerun to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
\newcommand{\mygraphics}[3][]{%
  \begin{center}%
    \includegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
    \captionon{figure}{#3}%
  \end{center}%
}
```

After first changing my script to this I got:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

However I `rm *.{aux,lof,lot,log,toc,out}` and then everything worked.

Comment: When you forward optional arguments, you should use `[{#1}]` instead of `[#1]`. In the case of `\includegraphics` it is unlikely to make a difference (because of the values which can be passed to `\includegraphics`), but in general this is more stable (your version can break if the optional arguments should contain a `]`).